# Jmeter test runs on GUI but not on maven

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am testing an endpoint using JMeter. The test runs successfully on GUI, but fails when I use maven with error below;

```
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

and this error in the log;

```
2017/05/04 16:03:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 0 ramp-up 0 perThread NaN delayedStart=false
```

Please kindly assist.

Comment: Your thread count is `0` I believe. Please check the number of threads in your test plan.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not 0 I set it to 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, the variable arguments for threads, rampUp etc. works on GUI but not on Maven. I solved it by setting these directly without using variables

Comment: Can you add more details on how you set these?